# The action didn't produce the valid JSON object in python file

Tags: python, json, ibm-cloud

I am using two actions of IBM cloud function - `write1` and `write2` (both using PYTHON).

I created a sequence that should pass value from `write1` to `write2`.

I wrote a PYTHON code in `write1` action but is throws some **JSON error**.

**Write 1 Python File:***

```py
    import os
    import sys
    import json
    import requests
    import ibm_boto3
    from ibm_botocore.client import Config, ClientError

    cos = ibm_boto3.resource("s3",
          ibm_api_key_id='my-api-key',
          ibm_service_instance_id='my-instance-id',
          config=Config(signature_version="oauth"),
         endpoint_url='https://s3.eu-gb.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud'
         )

    def get_item(bucket_name, item_name):
      a={"Retrieving item from bucket":bucket_name , "key": item_name}
      print(json.dumps(a))
    try:
        file = cos.Object(bucket_name, item_name).get()
        return file["Body"].read()
    except ClientError as be:
        w={"CLIENT ERROR":be}
        print(json.dumps(w))
    except Exception as e:
        y={"Unable to retrieve file contents":e}
        print(json.dumps(y))


    def test():
      x = get_item('cloud-college-bucket0','abc.txt') 
      print(x.decode('utf-8'))

    if x is not None:
        string_in_uppercase = x.upper();
        n={"String in Uppercase =":string_in_uppercase.decode('utf-8')}
        b=json.dumps(n)
        print(b)

    def main(dict):
      return test()      

    if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

**Error it throws:**

Results:

```
{
  "error": "**The action did not produce a valid JSON response**: null\n"
}

Logs:

[
  "2019-10-08T13:01:56.339677Z    stderr: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ibm_botocore/vendored/requests/api.py:67: DeprecationWarning: You are using the post() function from 'ibm_botocore.vendored.requests'.  This is not a public API in ibm_botocore and will be removed in the future. Additionally, this version of requests is out of date.  We recommend you install the requests package, 'import requests' directly, and use the requests.post() function instead.",

  "2019-10-08T13:01:56.339748Z    stderr: DeprecationWarning",

  "2019-10-08T13:01:56.339755Z    stderr: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ibm_botocore/vendored/requests/models.py:169: DeprecationWarning: 

Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working",

  "2019-10-08T13:01:56.339759Z    stderr: if isinstance(hook, collections.Callable):",

  "2019-10-08T13:01:56.339678Z    stdout: {\"Retrieving item from bucket\": \"cloud-college-bucket0\", \"key\": \"abc.txt\"}",

  "2019-10-08T13:01:56.339772Z    stdout: hello friends",

  "2019-10-08T13:01:56.339776Z    stdout: {\"String in Uppercase =\": \"HELLO FRIENDS\"}",

  "2019-10-08T13:01:56.340Z       stderr: The action did not initialize or run as expected. Log data might be missing."

]
```

It says `import request` which I did but still the problem persists.

I also say use `request.post` function but how and where to use is what I am unable to understand. **And how to solve this JSON issue?**

And the desired output is shown in the logs.

Comment: Do you mean `requests` package?

Answer (score 0):

From the first outset, I could see that the `test` function only prints the JSON but never returns it. But you if you see the sample Python action, it always should return a JSON

```
import sys

def main(dict):
    return { 'message': 'Hello world' }
```

Also, you can check the supported packages list with Python runtime [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-runtimes#python-packages) before using them in your action.

If you have a package that is not in the list, you can always [package Python code with a virtual environment in .zip files](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-prep#prep_python) or [Packaging code in Docker images](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-prep#prep_docker_pkg)